How can I connect misaligned range hood and elbow?
My range hood is misaligned from the elbow by 1.5". Is that too large a gap for flexible duct?  THis is an 8" hood.

I would like to avoid flexible duct since it traps grease and is difficult to clean in the future. Would it help to use semi rigid ducts? and would it help to remove the lowermost piece in the elbow (assuming that's possible), so that way the flexible/semi rigid ducting does not slope as much as it would currently.
I watched multiple videos to learn how to do this but still can't understand how exactly do I attach the upper end of the flexible duct into the elbow? In my case the air flow direction is upwards so while the lower end of flexible can wrap around the outside of the hood's damper, the upper end will have to go into the elbow, correct? how exactly do I do that?


Front view

Does the range hood have multiple mount-points for the fan? If there is room to slide it forward 1.5", that would fix the issue. Another possibility would be to push the elbow farther into the duct behind it, or to remove the elbow, trim the part going into the wall, and replace it -- if it would still be long enough to fit the duct without leakage.

@Triplefault I added front view pics to the post

I ended up using rigid round duct of the same diameter (8").
Steps are as follows:

Get 8" round rigid duct (change diameter to suit your hood) and cut it to make a pipe that's a few inches taller than the gap. (e.g. gap in my case was about 1" tall, so I used 4" height strip. But in hind sight, one could probably use 3" or even 2").
Cut it to be slightly longer than the gap
Crimp the upper end (the end that goes inside the upper duct). Tip: You don't need a duct crimper, use the claw side of a hammer. Plenty of videos explaining this online)
Pull the 90 elbow downwards as best as you can. The goal is to minimize the gap height
wrap the rigid round duct around the gap. If you have a gap with varying heights, simply keep inserting and spreading the rigid duct tin around the circumference (like you're rolling a piece of cloth around the joint). This is tricky and takes patience. Just don't give up
use sheet metal screws to secure this in place with the hood and elbow.
Use duct sealing compound to cover any large gaps. Then aluminium tape

An alternate would be to use a duct box as suggested by @isherwood below. I did not use that method since I saw the post after finishing the job but in hindsight, it may have been easier to implement.

A picture of the finished connector before taping would be worth a lot here.  Too late, I guess.  I think what you're saying is you just used a too-long straight connector, inserted the hood exhaust at an angle and crushed the connector around it?  Is that about right?

Don't use an elbow. Use a box duct.
You don't have to stick with bendy round tubes for things like this. If you build a box, say from an off-the-shelf rectangular duct of suitable size and associated endcaps, you can install drop fittings exactly where you need them.
Here's about the best image I can find to illustrate the concept. Your round ducts would be 90° apart on adjacent sides, and your box would be fully closed. If you're careful about measuring positions there's no reason it can't be a perfect fit.

image source

I wish I had read this response earlier. I ended up using some rigid round duct and adapting it around the gap-joint. It worked well. but this box duct may have made it easier. Thanks for sharing this. Will definitely help others in the future.

You're welcome. Please take the [tour] if you need a reminder how to respond to answers. I see that many of your questions are unresolved. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

There is no reasonable way to mate those two in their current positions.

If replacing the hood with a different one is an option for you, where the exhaust port is in the right place or is much lower so you can route a pipe between them, you should replace it.
You may be able to find a shorter radius 90 degree bend for the duct.  Not sure, but it looks like that one is the multi-segment-configurable kind.  If you look around you might find a fixed 90 that lands in the right place.
If the pipe goes all the way through the wall, and you have access from the other side, you could remove it from the wall and shorten the horizontal part so it ends up directly above the hood.

In the second two options the pipe only moves horizontally.  I don't know if you'll find a piece short enough to connect it, you might have to make one.

Worst case, you might have to smash open the wall and ceiling above the duct, and replace the last few feet of it so it's the right length and in the right place.  It appears this is inside a cabinet hidden from view so the wall repair doesn't have to be beautiful.


I would loosen the screws fastening the lower vent to the wall and shim it away from the wall to align with the top vent.

That appears that it'll create quite the gap at the wall.

This would create a gap in the wall. Plus the misalignment is along the left-right axis (when facing the hood), not along the front-back axis.

It's 2 or 3 inches, that's not shimming.  It's a range hood hanging on the wall.  Pushing it out 2 or 3 inches would need more than shims and then it would impede on the user of the range.
